# How can I make a slider with height of the webpage?

Tags: html, css

**Thanks everyone for replying I do believe I just needed larger pictures are it wasnt covering the whole height, I was reading online about how the sizes of the images don't matter but I guess they do. Thanks again everyone*** This has be solved

Hey guys I have created a slider that works at the moment. But it won't let me make it with a height of 100% can someone please help me? I am only using HTML and CSS. I have tried doing `body, html {height: 100%; }` which didn't work and also tried set it as a max-height/min-height and making it vh but nothing have worked so far.

```css
#slider{
 overflow:hidden;
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 -webkit-box-flex: 0; 
 height:100%;
}

#slider figure img{
 width:25%;
 float:left;
}

#slider figure{
 position: relative;
 width: 400%;
 margin:0;
 left:0;
 text-align:left;
 font-size:0;
 animation: 20s slidy infinite;
}

@keyframes slidy {
 0% { left: 0%; }
 20% { left: 0%; }
 25% { left: -100%; }
 45% { left: -100%; }
 50% { left: -200%; }
 70% { left: -200%; }
 75% { left: -300%; }
 100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
 <figure>
  <img src="pics\art1.jpg" />
  <img src="pics\art2.jpg" />
  <img src="pics\art3.jpg" />
  <img src="pics\art4.jpg" />
 </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  background: silver;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/vvse26ns/6/

Answer (score 2):

You can use viewport height and viewport width `height:100vh` and `width:100vw`.

Comment: what browser are you using? vh should work with most browser. which element are you putting this css properties on ?

Comment: I'm putting it into #slider and im using chrome

Answer (score 0):

Below properties should make it work.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvse26ns/1/)

Comment: What size of images you are using?

Comment: So I'm using 4 different sizes of images but I was reading up saying it doesnt matter about the size. one is 1800x800, second is 1283x800, third is 1714x960, fourth is 1285x960

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-height: 100%` and `witdh:auto`,

```
#slider{
    overflow:hidden;
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0; 
  min-height:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Tested in **FF** and **Chrome**

Comment: I also wantd the width to be 50% of the page